# How to say the bus left the stop in Russian?

Tags: перевод

Is that отойти? We have examples like that but I'm not sure about it...

Comment: Here's a discussion in Russian on the same topic (ходит vs ездит; подошёл/отошёл vs отъехал/подъехал):
http://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/48109/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%83%d1%81%d1%8b-%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%82-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%82

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better option is `отъехал`:

> Автобус отъехал от остановки.

`Отошел` is suitable also, but it is not the best option.

Comment: Нельзя сказать—"автобус уехал от остановки"? По-моему это подчеркивается, что автобуса нет. То есть, на остановке автобуса нет. Но, почем я знаю )) мб, что "уехать" неуместно тут.

Comment: @CoreyRoberts-Reynolds можно сказать и так, Но, по-моему, это не лучший вариант.

Comment: @CoreyRoberts-Reynolds , +1 for the question that is Truly interesting.  I'll post an update in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Colloquially, you would say just "автобус ушёл", omitting the whole bus stop from the context. 
Exactly as in the idiom "your bus has left the stop" meaning "you've missed your opportunity", "it's too late" - but a "train" is used: "твой поезд ушёл".

Comment: А как переведёте последнюю часть сложного предложения? `When we arrived at the station, the train left.`

Comment: `поезд уже ушёл` , "уже" indicates difference between simple past and present perfect, in this case.

Comment: Если `the train left`= `поезд ушёл`, то почему `the bus left the stop`= `автобус ушёл`? На каком основании выброшено слово `остановка` из OP?

Answer (score 1):

The best teacher in English is the English one. The same for Chinese. And for Russian. Here is what and how Russians **[write about it](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E0%E2%F2%EE%E1%F3%F1&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=6&lex2=%EE%F1%F2%E0%ED%EE%E2%EA%E0&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&lang=en)** in terms of verbs-of-motion — one of the most confusing topics in Russian.

`Отошел, отъехал` is good, if you want to preserve the **colloquial context**.

But if the question should have been appeared in official tests, or in the testing how one be able to recognize things in urban and cultural contexts **in the city, with its official language,** then I had admitted that `Автобус отправился от остановки.`*(по расписанию)*, is more accurate. Because exactly this phrase we are listening (and waiting to receive and recognize) to automated announcement systems for subway, bus and train stations.

[Usage example with a context](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&biw=1279&bih=706&tbm=bks&q=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%BE%D1%82&oq=%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%81+%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%BE%D1%82)

---

*CoreyRoberts-Reynolds* asked a question that is truly interesting:

Как сказать правильно:

```
  автобус  уехал от  остановки
             или                  ?
  автобус отъехал от остановки

  отъехал
    или      ?
  уехал от
```

A research into this issue shows that no rule had previously existed. That is normal. We must [[ask the Russian](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F3%E5%F5%E0%F2%FC&gramm1=praet&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=PR&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&p=1&lang=en)] to help us.

```
 Я, ты, он ... (either 
 all the pronouns ... ,
 or an adjective, predicative, adverbial pronoun, 
 or an animate person)                               уехал,   NOT отъехал
└────────────────subject─1───────────────────────┘
```

So, in case of `автобус` which is an inanimate thing, we do not use **`уехал`**.

```
subject─2 отъехал
```

[is widely used](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=&gramm1=S&sem1=r%3Aabstr%20%7C%20(pt%3Apart%20%7C%20pt%3Aqtm%20%7C%20pt%3Aset)&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%EE%F2%FA%E5%F5%E0%F2%FC&gramm2=praet&sem2=&sem-mod3=sem&sem-mod3=sem2&flags2=&m3=&parent3=0&level3=0&min3=1&max3=1&lex3=&gramm3=PR&sem3=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags3=&m2=&lang=en),
where `subject─2 = inanimate things`.

What about

```
уехал от  [кого?чего?]
```

In ≈90% was used the `[subject─1]`. [Proof](http://search-beta.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F3%E5%F5%E0%F2%FC&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%EE%F2&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=&p=2&lang=en).

In the rest of the cases are

```
 уехал от семейных неприятностей [Толстой]             | which may be classified as
 уехал от чудес: в тропиках их нет [Гончаров. (1855)]  | something, that causes of 
 уехал от назойливых вопросов                          | mood swings. Something in
 уехал от предстоящих платежей                         | our mind, that can act as 
 уехал от скуки                                        | it is animated and have
                                                       | intent towards to us.
```

Comment: `уехал` или `ушёл` is more common used in colloquial language. I think it's because vehicles like автобус, автомобиль, корабль, самолёт are treated like animate in this case.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin , Since Russians are attributing to all things of which they understands the essence, including the word "essence" itself, "gender", why not attributing to it the property a qualitative field that has a character in some human sense? We do.

Comment: I've read this comment through 3 or 4 times, and it's still unclear for me what do you mean. Gender -- yes, we do attribute. Is автобус a character in some human sense? Sure. Yes, it describes the reason to treat it as an animate, in the sense it _can_ do something by itself, do we want it or not, e.g. leave. "Отошёл" or "отъехал" may be more formal, yes. But colloquial use is "ушёл" or "уехал" though...

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin , вот Вам три слова, как в OP: `автобус, уйти, остановка`. Попробуйте написать законченное предложение на русском, в прошедшем времени.

Comment: OK, you win. "Автобус ушёл" is closer to "The bus is _gone_", but "leave" or "left the bus stop" is closer to "отошёл" or "отъехал", I believe.

Comment: В первом комменте я пропустил *of*, но не думаю, что такая ошибка помешала понять — имелась ввиду одушевленность, подразумевающаяся у русскоговорящего в контексте вокруг слова `уйти/уехать`. Она тем сильнее проявляется, чем дальше от формы в инфинитиве и чем больше контекста. Поэтому сопоставление `поезд ушёл` и `поезд ушёл от остановки` ярко проявляет, в чём здесь дело. Выиграли оба ))

Answer (score 0):

"Отойти от" - for ships or vessels (everyday talk)

"Отвалить от" - for ships or vessels (marine jargon)

"Отправиться из" - for trains

"Вылететь из" - for planes

"Отъехать от" - for buses, autos etc.

Comment: `Отправляется с остановки, отправился с остановки` also suited to bus, moreover, it is only terms for official language.

Comment: @Avtokod "Отправляется" sounds a bit awkward and does not suit well for ordinary buses. Much better for intercity buses though. But I'm agree there are more cases to consider.

Comment: Что звучит более нескладно: `поел` или `принял пищу`? Вы не можете что-то отвергнуть, верно? Оба варианта равнозначны и употребительны.  Неуклюжесть проявится при употреблении(использовании) в несоответствующем  контексте. Всем управляет контекст. Когда я изучил польский язык, на уровне своего родного русского, то вдруг обнаружил, что попадая в определенную обстановку и рассуждая в ее контексте, мои фразы становятся смешны и нелепы. Теперь я легко распознаю эти же затруднения у изучающих русский язык.

Comment: @Avtokod Ну не получается у меня придумать контекст, в котором про обычный городской автобус можно без натяга сказать: автобус номер такой-то отправляется с остановки такой-то. Ну не поезд он и не метро, хоть тресни. Ладно, если он из Петербурга в Москву отправляется, а от гастронома-то до рынка...

Comment: А для чего же я в своем ответе оставил ссылку "Usage example with a context"? ))

Comment: @Avtokod Ну да, еще экскурсионные. Экскурсионные и междугородние - других там не вижу.